# How can I learn algorithms for programming contests?

Tags: java, algorithm

What are the best ways to learn algorithms for programming contests such as USACO. I need to start learning algorithms as I have just gotten into the silver division. Are there any good books or tutorials to learn algorithms and techniques such as Dijkstra's, Dynamic Programming, Flood-fill, etc. in Java and actually be able to know how to implement them for problems? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Taking a class at a local college is probably the best place to start. Otherwise picking up a book on algorithms is another option.

Comment: How about the book [Programming Challenges](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Challenges-Steven-S-Skiena/dp/0387001638/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1336971355&sr=8-1)?

Comment: Avoid college courses like the plague. Go to SPOJ, Topcoder, etc, instead, like nims said, read books. I am not anti-education or anything (I do have a masters in CS) but algorithmic programming courses in universities are targeted at the lowest common denominator and will literally make you dumber for going through them. It is ridiculous how low they set the bar and how they don't bother teaching problem solving skills. Although you may be able to find some related club or something at a university that has past IOI (or other competition) competitors who can teach you a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I learn to solve other algorithms problems like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2112554/how-can-i-learn-how-to-solve-other-algorithms-problems-like-this)

Answer (score 4):

1. PRACTICE! This is the most important point. solve problems regularly in online judges like [SPOJ](http://SPOJ.pl) , [UVA](http://uva.onlinejudge.org), etc. Solving more problems will familiarize you with the type and format of questions that are asked in the programming competitions. This way, you will also increase your ability to derive your own algorithms and see through problems.
2. Get [Introduction To Algorithm, Cormen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937). It is an excellent book for learning and analysis of algorithms and data structures.

Comment: [UVA](http://uva.onlinejudge.com/) link seems broken

Comment: link fixed, but the UVA site is down for the moment.

Comment: I disagree that CLRS (*Introduction to Algorithms*) is the best book for beginners. It's extremely mathy and dry. Instead, try Vazirani and Dasgupta's *Algorithms* - the pre-press version is available as a free PDF: Google for it. It's written in a much more engaging style, and still manages to hit most of the required points - perhaps with less rigour, but you can get that from CLRS afterwards.